# want to show the newly uploaded image on page reload and page refreshing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form in which I have an upload button and a remove button.

Initially an image is displaying on the form which I am retrieving from database (Mysql).

And when I am uploading a new image, the image gets uploaded but the previous image (which is the initial image) also gets displayed on the box.

When I am refreshing the page or reloading it then no image is shown,what I am getting is a box without any image (i.e of initial image).

I want to make that uploaded image shown always until new image is uploaded or removed and also to remove that box of my initial image. How can I do that in php?
This code is showing initial image when opening my form and till i am not updating:

```
// Connection to Database 
$result1= mysql_query( "SELECT images FROM $table" ) or die("SELECT Error".mysql_error()); 
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
echo "<img src='data:images/jpeg;base64," .base64_encode( $row['images'])."'width='100' height='100' />";
```

This is the code to upload the image:

```
$UPLOADDIR = "upload/";
if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
        foreach ($_FILES as $key => $value)
        {
            $image_tmp = $value['tmp_name'];
            $image = $value['name'];
            $image_file = "{$UPLOADDIR}{$image}";
            if(move_uploaded_file($image_tmp,$image_file))
        {
                 mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
             $result1= mysql_query( "SELECT images FROM $table WHERE images='$image'" )or die("SELECT Error: ".mysql_error()); 
         $sql="DELETE FROM $table WHERE ID!=1";
         mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");
         $ret=mysql_query($sql,$conn);
         if(!$ret)
        {
             die(mysql_error());
        }
                $query = "INSERT INTO $table (images) VALUES ('$image')";
        $data = mysql_query ($query)or die(mysql_error());
        echo <<<HEREDOC
                <div style="float:left;margin-right:10px;">
                <img src="{$image_file}" alt="file not found" height="100"         width="100"/>            
                </br>
                </div>
                HEREDOC;
        }
        else
       {
            echo "<h1>image file upload failed, image too big after compression</h1>";
       }
    }
}
else
{
    ?> 
    <form name='newad' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><input type='file' name='image'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input name='Submit' type='submit' value='Upload image'></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <?php
}
?>
```

My uploaded image is saving in database and uploaded image is shown after clicking on upload button but when I reload the page or open the form again then there is no image.

Comment: We will require your code if we are to see where you are going wrong.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor- I have copied my code here.Now u may have a look over it.

Comment: @Justice- I have copied my code here.Now u may have a look over it.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the script, store the posted file if it was uploaded.
Then later fetch the stored image from the database to display.

edit for more details:

When you submit the form to a php script, check if the $_FILES global contains the uploaded file. If so, store the file (preferrably with a new, random name) somewhere in an image directory, and the location in the database. Then further down when you display the image, you retrieve the url to the image from the database to put in the img src tag.

But you should just start fiddling around till it's right.

Comment: @BazzPsychoNut- Actually I am new in php. Can you explain further what are u trying 2 say?

Comment: @BazzPsychoNut- I am retreving uploaded image from database but its just storing in database not displaying on webpage.